# Mapping a MAC address of a Level2 switch to a name

Tags: unix, bridge, mac-address

With `brctl showmacs br0` I can get a list of all the MAC addresses found on a bridge.

To make this more human-readable, I translate the output by replacing the MAC addresses with hostnames (for fixed addresses) that I find in my `dhcpd.conf` file.

This enables me to translate all MACs that have used my DHCP server to get a fixed IP address.

So instead of this:

```
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
  1 f6:06:c6:f9:70:df   no          19.75
  2 fc:44:82:aa:7b:2f   no           0.00
...
```

...I am seeing this instead:

```
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
  1 printer             no          19.75
  2 ipad-john           no           0.00
```

However, the output of the brctl command also includes MAC addresses of Level-2 switches on the network.

What would be a good way to tag those switches with some sort of name-tag, so that the output of brctl is more descriptive?

Is there any mechanism in Debian or Ubuntu that keeps track of Level-2 switches on the network?

As there is no IP address associated with L2 switches, there is no hostname either. But surely networking professionals must have some way of tracking this stuff?

### UPDATE

One example of a level 2 switch showing a MAC (and having a MAC address printed on the case) is QNAP [QSW-1105](https://www.qnap.com/en-us/product/qsw-1105-5t)-5T, which is an unmanaged switch.

Comment: My networking knowledge is a bit rusty, but I think non-managed L2 switches are effectively transparent: they either just pass traffic in the right direction or in all directions. They don't have a MAC address because if they work correctly, they are invisible. Managed switches, on the other hand, will have both MAC and IP addresses or a dedicated management interface.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what MACs you're seeing? An L2 switch doesn't usually have its own MAC address(es) unless there is a management interface of some kind. A management interface *can* be assigned an IP/hostname, so it could look like any other entry on your list